# How to retrieve data from a ComplexType Sql Server stored procedure inside C# project built with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have written a SQL Server stored procedure which returns data by using inner join on multiple table. Meaning it is not returning any specific Entity.

Here is my procedure:

```
CREATE proc usp_viewlog_query

as
SET FMTONLY OFF

declare @start_date datetime
set @start_date = DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())

select distinct v.VehilceId, v.Year, vs.StatusName, vp.PhotoName,
sp.StateName, v.Price, v.ManufacturerId, v.Model, v.UrlAlias into #t from Vehicle v
inner join (
    select distinct  top 10 VehicleId, ViewedOn from ViewLog where ViewedOn >= @start_date --order by ViewedOn desc
) vl on v.VehilceId = vl.VehicleId
inner join StateParish sp on v.StateCode = sp.StateCode
inner join VehiclePosition vs on v.StatusCode = vs.StatusCode
left join (select top 1 vehicleid, photoname from VehiclePhoto) vp on v.VehilceId = vp.VehicleId

update #t set PhotoName = (select top 1 photoname from VehiclePhoto where VehicleId = #t.VehilceId)

select
VehilceId as VehicleId, [year], StatusName, 
PhotoName, StateName, Price, ManufacturerId,
Model, UrlAlias
from #t
drop table #t
```

I added the above procedure using `Update Model From Database` and then imported the function as a `ComplexType`.

But how can I fetch the records from above `dataset` into my project and access it? I have searched for sometime but all I am getting is how to import the procedure, which I have done already.

I don't know the code to access the above function and grab the data inside my project.

Answer (score 0):

First create a type with same property names as your procedure's column names, for example:-

```
public class MyComplexType
{
    public int VehilceId { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    public string PhotoName { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

then call your proc:-

```
using(var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<MyComplexType>("usp_viewlog_query").ToList();
}
```